# AWS SDK PHP - Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

There seems to be an error either in the documentation or the SDK itself.
The SDK keeps looking for the standard credentials file while there is none.

```
require('aws/aws-autoloader.php');
use Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
$profile = 'default';
$inipath = '/www/test/.test/credentials.ini';
$provider = CredentialProvider::ini($profile, $inipath);
$provider = CredentialProvider::memoize($provider);

use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
try {

    $s3Client = new S3Client([
            'profile' => 'default',
            'region' => 'eu-central-1',
            'version' => '2006-03-01',
            'credentials' => $provider,
    ]);
```

It fails with this error:

```
Uncaught Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials in /www/test/aws/Aws/Credentials/CredentialProvider.php:394
```

Does anybody have a clue on how fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed 'profile' => 'default', from the s3client and it worked.
It seemed the profiles were defined twice.

Comment: Not sure I understand this answer. Are you saying that your .aws/credentials file had two [default] sections and you removed one of them? Or that you modified your new S3Client() call to not indicate the default profile?

Comment: See line 4 and line 12 they were duplicated.

Comment: I was having the same issue - this has solved it. Thanks!